# WSO2 EI - fileconnector.readSpecifiedLines not working properly

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

we are using **WSO2 EI version 6.1.1** and **fileconnector 2.0.10**

We are trying to use the readSpecifiedLine operation from file connector but it always read the entire file. In this particular case we are trying to read a CSV skipping the header.

```
<fileconnector.readSpecifiedLines>
   <source>{$ctx:sourceFile}</source>
   <contentType>text/plain</contentType>
   <start>2</start>
   <end>3</end>
</fileconnector.readSpecifiedLines>
```

Did someone was able to use this operation successfully, can't find much on google either. thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is already a bug. Reported bug Jira Id.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBCONNECT-271

Comment: Hi, do we have any update on when the fix's gonna be merged, I'm tempted to approve the review myself. Have you tested that change? We would really appreciate that fix. thanks.

Comment: Hi, changes are already merged. Maybe in the next release, it will be available.

Comment: Hi, fix is available in the 2.0.12 version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with the version 2.0.12. Please download and redeploy the latest connector [1] from WSO2 store.

[1] https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/5d6de1a4-1fa7-434e-863f-95c8533d3df2